# Headphone Jack Listener Android

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, android-audiomanager

Does anyone know how I can detect if the headphone jack on a device is unplugged on Android? I have a music player and I need to pause the music when the headphones are unplugged. The closest thing I have found is using the `AudioManager`. Is that the right direction to go?

Comment: Here's a good implementation of Android MediaPlayer @ [GitHub](https://github.com/philippMarchenko/Music/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/devphill/music/player/MusicPlayer.java). It's integrated with a `MediaSessionCompat` and a `HeadsetListener` -- an implementation of `BroadcastReceiver` that pauses playback when headphones are disconnected. Also, it's handling Audio Focus through `AudioManager`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
private class NoisyAudioStreamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            pause();
        }
    }
}

private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);

private void startPlayback() {
    registerReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver(), intentFilter);
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    unregisterReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver);
}
```

I found the answer at this link: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html

Comment: Although I don't have the full details on how to do it, I believe you can use "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" in something along the lines of :IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        HeadsetStateReceiver receiver = new headsetStateReceiver();
        registerReceiver(this.toggleDeviceConnectionState(), receiverFilter);

Comment: @shim Just check the documentation of Intent(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG), and you are kinda right: Yes, that Intent Filter exist, but from API21+ they suggest you to use AudioManager instead. I think the reason why is because BECOMING_NOISY also takes other kinds of audio output devices (e.g. bluetooth headset) into account, e.g. if bluetooth headset disconnected it should also make that broadcast. I am trying it now, but for backward compatibility I guess both method needs to be implemented...