# How can I lower the MediaPlayer volume when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: android, media-player, volume, android-audiomanager, headphones

Targeting Android 2.2.

I need to check if the user is using speaker or headphones when listening to media. So far, the best I've found is the [isWiredHeadsetOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29) method. Too bad it's been deprecated. Is there a better method to know if headphones are plugged in?

The real question is: How can I lower the `MediaPlayer` volume when headphones are plugged in? At playback start (i.e. through a boolean check) and during playback (i.e. through an event)?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a link because I think it will help to answer and SO converted to a comment. The following code is from and I take no credit. They use it to listen for unplugged headphones but the same concept should be possible for what you are asking for:
[Headphone Jack Listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985343/headphone-jack-listener-android)

```
private class NoisyAudioStreamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            pause();
        }
    }
}

private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);

private void startPlayback() {
    registerReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver(), intentFilter);
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    unregisterReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver);
}
```