# How to disable mute when headphones is connected

Tags: java, android

I have mediaplayer for playing mp3. If I connect the headphones, the music is muted and I have to manually open volume settings and set it to max. It's happen even when I seek sound by using seekbar.

Note: If the headphones is not connected, it works perfectly.

How can I disable the mute if headphones is connected?

Here is the part of my code:

```
progress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser && currentPlayingSong != null) {
                int volume = getVolume();
                setVolume(0);
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                setVolume(volume);
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**:
Here is method for getVolume:

```
private int getVolume() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    return audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

Comment: int volume = currentPlayingSong.getVolume(); //Here is the problem

Comment: I added another piece of code - getVolume. Can it really be a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9985343 this might help

Comment: in this case, all is correct. have you given in manifest permission?

Comment: In manifest I have: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK and android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.